# В чём отличие команд от обработчиков событий?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, wpf-commands

В WPF и MVVM существует четкая парадигма использовать команды, наследующие ICommand, отделяющие логику от представления и т.д. Однако, после перехода с событийной модели на MVVM не совсем понятно, в чём их отличия от обработчиков событий?

Comment: Вы ведь сами написали `отделяющие логику от представления`.

Comment: Хотелось бы более развернутого ответа, не повторяющего мои же слова или документации MSDN, потому что, если знать, в чём отличия, то так легче понять, что из себя представляет та или другая структура. То, что они отделяют логику от представления - это их смысл, а то, как они это делают и почему обработчики событий не подходят - вот, что мне интересно.

Comment: Обработчики подходят, почему нет? Просто в WPF есть двухсторонние привязки, которые делают код менее связным и их удобнее использовать чем события

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробую своими словами, так как сам недавно слез с WinForms-подхода на MVVM и рад этому. Мой дилетантский взгляд, на гениальность не претендую.

*События*

- Обработчик события получает ссылку на контрол в `sender` и все необходимые данные о событии в `EventArgs`. Далее можно делать с ними что требуется: менять поведение контрола, или слать данные куда подальше. Набор входных данных фиксирован и не кастомизируется.
- Событие вызывается тогда, когда нам надо, нажата клавиша, наведена мышь, и так далее. Есть много разных событий, которые могут подойти практически под любой вид задач.

*Но*

- Находятся все в одном классе
- Сложно тестировать

*Команды*

- Находятся где угодно, куда можно ссылаться при объявлении `Binding`, по умолчанию там, куда ссылается `DataContext`.
- В команду можно передать любой аргумент.
- Команду можно вызвать когда надо через прямое подключение, например к кнопке, или через `KeyBindings`.
- Разрешено ли выполнять команду, узнать можно до начала ее выполнения, условие помещается в `CanExecute`. При этом многие контролы имеют встроенную реакцию на CanExecute, и например сами могут переводить свое состояние в `Disabled`, если `CanExecute` вернет `false` (например `MenuItem` или `Button`). Это удобно.
- Легко тестировать просто вызвав команду отдельно из тестового метода.

Команды при этом не всегда нужны, например они не нужны, если мы хотим что-то сделать, если у контрола меняется какое-то свойство. В этом случае мы просто можем забиндить само свойство и выполнять код по факту изменения свойства. Так же команды не нужны, чтобы менять внешний вид или поведение контрола. В 99% случаев, это решается прямо в xaml с помощью стилей и шаблонов.

На текущий момент недостатков у команд я не вижу, просто их назначение совсем другое, не такое как у обработчиков событий, я бы даже сравнивать не стал.

*Наиболее удобный способ использования команд, на мой взгляд, лучше всего описан [здесь](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2009/february/patterns-wpf-apps-with-the-model-view-viewmodel-design-pattern) в разделе **Relaying Command Logic**.*

Answer (score 2):

Думаю, что основное преимущество команд - это разделение логики и представления (то, что вы сказали). Немного уточнений:

- Вы создаёте одну команду и можете использовать её во многих `View`, много раз. Событие же тесно связано с источником, поэтому обработчик вешается на ту `View`, на котором висит это событие;
- Это ведёт к тому, что команды проще тестировать;
- У команд есть два метода: `Execute` и `CanExecute`. Очень удобно то, что в `CanExecute` можно определить условие, когда команда сработае, а когда нет.

Также можно почитать вот эти две ссылки (правда они на английском):

1) https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-3.5/ms752308(v=vs.90)?redirectedfrom=MSDN

2) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8452/custom-wpf-command-pattern-example

В дополнении можно добавить, что в wpf реализовано много встроенных команд. Тут есть их список: https://metanit.com/sharp/wpf/7.1.php